# Bounding tail conditional expectation of a random variable given variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, upper-lower-bounds

Given a random variable $X$ with CDF $F(X)$, mean $E(X)=0$, and variance $Var(X) =\sigma^2$, I would like to bound the tail conditional expectation where $X$ is in the tail with probability $1-p$:

$E(X|X\geq F^{-1}(p)) = \frac{1}{1-p}\int_{F^{-1}(p)}^\infty X dF(X)$

A nice way to get an upper bound is via a Chebyshev-type inequality: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177697276, which suggests:

$E(X|X\geq F^{-1}(p)) \leq \sigma \sqrt{\frac{p}{1-p}}$

But how can we get a lower bound? Intuitively, since $E(X) = 0$, we must have:

$E(X|X\geq F^{-1}(p)) \geq 0$

But that doesn't use the dispersion of the RV at all. Intuitively, if $\sigma$ is large and $E(X)=0$, the lower bound should be large, so the lower bound should grow with $\sigma$. But I have no idea how to formalize it. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x\in\mathbb R$, we clearly have $E(X|X\ge x)\ge x$. We also have $E(X|X\ge x)\ge0$. This is a consequence of the previous fact if $x\ge0$, and if $x<0$ this follows since
$$E(X\mathbf1_{\{X\ge x\}})=E(X)-E(X\mathbf1_{\{X<x\}})\ge-x\mathbb P(X<x)\ge0.$$
In fact, $E\big(X|X\ge F^{-1}(p)\big)\ge F^{-1}(p)\vee0$ is optimal. If $F^{-1}(p)<0$, we can see this easily by considering a random variable $X$ which satisfies $P(X=x)=p$, $P(X=\frac{p|x|}{1-p})=1-p$ for some $x<0$. It is straightforward to check that $E(X)=0$, $x=F^{-1}(p)$, and $X\ge x$ almost surely, so in particular $E(X|X\ge x)=E(X)=0$.

If $F^{-1}(p)\ge0$, fix $x\ge0,\epsilon>0$ and construct a random variable $X$ satisfying
$$P(X=x+\epsilon)=1-p,\quad P(X=x)=\frac p2,\quad P(X=-q)=\frac p2$$
where $q$ is chosen so that $(1-p)(x+\epsilon)+px/2=pq/2$. Again, it is clear that $F^{-1}(p)=x$ and $E(X)=0$, and while you may explicitly calculate $E(X|X\ge x)$, the important thing to note is $E(X|X\ge x)\in[x,x+\epsilon]$.  This shows the inequality is optimal.

Comment: Thanks!! This is very helpful. Suppose we don’t know $x$ or $F^{-1}(p)$, however, since knowing the CDF would already give us the conditionals, this reduces the problem to constructing a bound for $F^{-1}(p)$ given $p$ and the mean/variance. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're asking. Well, if you look at my first example, you see that $\operatorname{Var}(X)=px^2/(1-p)$, so choosing $x=-\sigma\sqrt{(1-p)/p}$ we see that we have found a random variable $X$ with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$ which nevertheless satisfies $E\big(X|X\ge F^{-1}(p)\big)=0$.